# how to save a cropped uiview screen shot using a extension market

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimage, extension-methods

My extension method right now takes a screenshot of the entire uiview inside of the view controller. I would like to use the same function to do the same thing only take a exact area of of the uiview instead of the whole view. Specifically I would like to capture x:0,y:0,length 200,Height 200,

```
    func screenshot() -> UIImage {
        let imageSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size as CGSize;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        for obj : AnyObject in UIApplication.shared.windows {
            if let window = obj as? UIWindow {
                if window.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIWindow.screen)) || window.screen == UIScreen.main {
                    // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
                    context!.saveGState();
                    // Center the context around the window's anchor point
                    context!.translateBy(x: window.center.x, y: window.center
                        .y);
                    // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
                    context!.concatenate(window.transform);
                    // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
                    context!.translateBy(x: -window.bounds.size.width * window.layer.anchorPoint.x,
                                         y: -window.bounds.size.height * window.layer.anchorPoint.y);

                    // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
                    window.layer.render(in: context!)

                    // Restore the context
                    context!.restoreGState();
                }
            }
        }
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        return image!
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
extension UIView {
    func screenshot(for rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect).image { _ in
            drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bounds.size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

This makes it a bit more reusable, but you can change it to be a hardcoded value if you want.

`let image = self.view.screenshot(for: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))`